# Dart - Help me understand how this code on Dart works

Tags: dart, dart-async

Please help me understand how this code works. And why it works that way.

Variables `res` in example is `Stream<Row>`.

I want to return `Future<List>` from the `processQueryResult` method. This code works as it should and the result that I get is correct.

**Example 1**

```dart
Future<List> processQueryResult(mysql.Results res) {
  List data = [];

  res.toList().then((List<mysql.Row> rows) {
    rows.forEach((mysql.Row row) {
      data.add({name: row.name, email: row.email});
    });
  });

  return new Future<List>(() {
    return data;
  });
}
```

In result `data` contains all need data.

But tell me please, why when I move this part of code

```dart
res.toList().then((List<mysql.Row> rows) {
  rows.forEach((mysql.Row row) {
    data.add({name: row.name, email: row.email});
  });
});
```

To

```dart
return new Future<List>(() {

  res.toList().then((List<mysql.Row> rows) {
    rows.forEach((mysql.Row row) {
      data.add({name: row.name, email: row.email});
    });
  });

  return data;

});
```

Finally code look that (**Example 2**):

```dart
Future<List> processQueryResult(mysql.Results res) {
  List data = [];      

  return new Future<List>(() {
    res.toList().then((List<mysql.Row> rows) {
      rows.forEach((mysql.Row row) {
       data.add({name: row.name, email: row.email});
      });
    });

    return data;
  });
}
```

Then in result I get empty list.

For the test I use this function:

```dart
testResult() {

  mysql.Results res = ... // get results;
  processQueryResult(res).then((data) {
    print(data);
  })

}
```

When code of `processQueryResult` like **Example 1**, then I get correct data, but when code of `processQueryResult` like **Example 2** - I get empty List.

Tell me please, why is this happening?

I would be glad if you give a link to the appropriate article or documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
return new Future<List>(() {

  res.toList() // <== 1.) registers a future for later execution // <== 3.) execute `toList()`
    .then((List<mysql.Row> rows) {
    rows.forEach((mysql.Row row) { // <== 4.) execute rows.forEach
      data.add({name: row.name, email: row.email});
    });
  });

  return data; // <== 2.) return data

});
```

3.) is executed after the code calling the above code has finished all sync execution

```dart
return new Future<List>(() {

  return res.toList() // <== returning the future keeps the async parts connected
                      // and one is executed after the other
    .then((List<mysql.Row> rows) {
      rows.forEach((mysql.Row row) { // <== 4.) execute rows.forEach
        data.add({name: row.name, email: row.email});
      });
    })
    .then((_) data);  // <== the same here, return data **after** the previous statements are finished
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help! You are the coolest person on stackoverflow!